# Select datepart year then group by and having datepart

Tags: sql-server

I did this and its working properly but now I want how what to do that show month and year like 01 2018:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SaleChart]  
    (@FromYear NVARCHAR(50),
     @ToYear NVARCHAR(50))
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        SUM ([TotalQty]) AS 'Total',
        DATEPART (yyyy, [Date]) AS 'Year'
    FROM
        [dbo].[SalesMainTable]
    GROUP BY 
        DATEPART (yyyy, [Date])
    HAVING 
        DATEPART (yyyy, [Date]) >= @FromYear 
        AND DATEPART (yyyy, [Date]) <= @ToYear
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

Note `having` it only required when filtering on aggregate values. Just use `where` otherwise.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SaleChart]
(
  @FromYear NVARCHAR(50)
  , @ToYear NVARCHAR(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT 
    DATEPART(year, [Date]) AS 'Year'
    , DATEPART(month, [Date]) AS 'Month'
    , SUM ([TotalQty]) AS 'Total'
  FROM [dbo].[SalesMainTable]
  WHERE DATEPART(year, [Date]) >= @FromYear AND DATEPART(year, [Date]) <= @ToYear
  GROUP BY DATEPART(year, [Date]), DATEPART(month, [Date])
END
```

Edit: If you are looking to filter by month as well I would pass that in as a date as follows:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SaleChart]
(
  @FromDate date
  , @ToDate date
)
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT 
    DATEPART(year, [Date]) AS 'Year'
    , DATEPART(month, [Date]) AS 'Month'
    , SUM ([TotalQty]) AS 'Total'
  FROM [dbo].[SalesMainTable]
  WHERE [Date] >= @FromDate and [Date] <= @ToDate
  GROUP BY DATEPART(year, [Date]), DATEPART(month, [Date])
END
```

Comment: thank u sir it worked, but a little problem when i give 01/2018 in one field and 09/2018 in second one

Comment: error: Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SaleVyMOnthChart, Line 13
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '01/2018' to data type int.

Comment: So you want to be able to filter by month as well as display the month?

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near '/'.

Comment: Correct, I am suggesting for ease of operation that you pass in a full date instead of a string which needs to be manipulated. So pass in '01 jan 2018' for example and then your end date as '31 jan 2018'

Answer (score 0):

Add select and group by Month and Day

```
SELECT 
       SUM ([TotalQty]) AS 'Total',
       DATEPART (year,[Date]) AS 'Year',
       DATEPART (month,[Date]) AS 'Month',
       DATEPART (day,[Date]) AS 'Day'
FROM [dbo].[SalesMainTable]

where  DATEPART (year,[Date]) between @FromYear and @ToYear

GROUP BY DATEPART (year,[Date])
       ,DATEPART (month,[Date])
       ,DATEPART (day,[Date])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the right one

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SaleChartnew]
( @FromYear NVARCHAR(50), @ToYear NVARCHAR(50) ) 
AS BEGIN

    DECLARE 
        @YearFrom   INT = RIGHT(@FromYear, 4)
    ,   @YearTo     INT = RIGHT(@ToYear, 4)
    ,   @MonthFrom  INT = LEFT(@FromYear, CHARINDEX('/',@FromYear) - 1)
    ,   @MonthTo    INT = LEFT(@ToYear, CHARINDEX('/',@ToYear) - 1)
    ,   @StartDate  DATE
    ,   @EndDate    DATE 


    SET @StartDate = DATEFROMPARTS(@YearFrom, @MonthFrom, 1)
    SET @EndDate   = DATEFROMPARTS(@YearTo, @MonthTo + 1, 1)
    SET @EndDate   = DATEADD(DAY, -1, @EndDate)


    SELECT 
        SUM([TotalQty]) AS 'Total'
     ,  YEAR([Date])    AS 'Year'
     ,  MONTH([Date])   AS 'Month'
    FROM 
        [dbo].[SalesMainTable]

        where
     [Date] >= @StartDate
    AND [Date] <= @EndDate

    GROUP BY 
       Datepart (YEAR,[Date]),DATEPART (MONTH,[Date])
    ,   MONTH([Date])   



END
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you're looking for something like this :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SaleChart]
( @FromYear NVARCHAR(50), @ToYear NVARCHAR(50) ) 
AS BEGIN

    DECLARE 
        @YearFrom   INT = RIGHT(@FromYear, 4)
    ,   @YearTo     INT = RIGHT(@ToYear, 4)
    ,   @MonthFrom  INT = LEFT(@FromYear, CHARINDEX('/',@FromYear) - 1)
    ,   @MonthTo    INT = LEFT(@ToYear, CHARINDEX('/',@ToYear) - 1)
    ,   @StartDate  DATE
    ,   @EndDate    DATE 


    SET @StartDate = DATEFROMPARTS(@YearFrom, @MonthFrom, 1)
    SET @EndDate   = DATEFROMPARTS(@YearTo, @MonthTo + 1, 1)
    SET @EndDate   = DATEADD(DAY, -1, @EndDate)


    SELECT 
        SUM([TotalQty]) AS 'Total'
     ,  YEAR([Date])    AS 'Year'
     ,  MONTH([Date])   AS 'Month'
    FROM 
        [dbo].[SalesMainTable]
    GROUP BY 
        YEAR([Date])
    ,   MONTH([Date])   
    HAVING 
        [Date] >= @StartDate
    AND [Date] <= @EndDate

END
```

The current date format input used is `mm/yyyy` for both parameters. if you are going to change the date format in the future, you'll need to adjust the LEFT and RIGHT for each of them and maybe use SUBSTRING instead. Not sure why you used this way of date input as it'll make things complicated. I would suggest you to use one of the standard date formats that SQL Server understands such as `yyyy-mm-dd` as inputs, and in your query, you can use YEAR,MONTH, DAY or DATEPART functions to group the results as you need.

Comment: Thank U Sir. U R Great... I changed a little and it worked